# Gmail is not displaying image in html email

Tags: c#, html, html-email, attachment, email-attachments

I am making Email-Templates with HTML and I test it in C# with the MailMessage and the Attachment class. In the HTML code I have an image called mail_header.png and later in the C# code I use an Attachment on its sourcelink. Strangely it works in Outlook but Gmail is not displaying the image. I have already read some similar posts on this topic, but all of the answers refered to a weblink and in my situation a weblink is not a thing. It seems not to be a security issue because I already turned on that all images in Gmail are displayed. Is there a workaround so that I can still use the attachment?

I use this img tag in my html code:

```
<img src="mail_header.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display: block;" content="mail_header.png";>
```

Attachment:

```
var att = new Attachment(Resources.ResourceGovernor.GetMailHeader(), "mail_header.png", "image/png");
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(att);
```

Output (eml file):

[Link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiOBV.jpg)

Comment: Please show us that updated code. Also consider sending the email to www.guerrillamail.com and sharing the actual raw output that is generated.

Comment: Cut the email down to the absolute minimum to reproduce the issue - a [mcve]. We don't care about your company's data, so remove that. Leave in just enough so we can see what is generated and received by Guerrilla.

Comment: I was hoping to see the output, as shown in Guerrilla Mail. I mean text, not an image.